# MQTT client dropping out then the HTTP communication is called

Tags: https, arduino, mqtt

I am working on a project presently were I am communicating between 3 MKR1000 boards through shiftr.io

The scenario is that there are 2 field sensors (senders) measuring humidity transmitting back to a receiver hub.

I am also using a pushing box to send data from the senders to google sheets (GS) this alert is activated/deactivated from the receiver, but the actual sending of data to GS is handled by the sender boards.

So the problem-  when I toggle the google sheet function the connection to the broker (shiftr.io) drops out. I got around the problem by making it reconnect to MQTT broker each time it sends data to GS..but this is not correct... and it cannot be toggled off now.

The wifi is still connected as the data is logged to GS.

when I comment out the function to send the data to GS it toggles on and off fine.

The code for sending the data to GS is written in HTTP, is there a conflict between the 2 protocols?

I am unsure what code to post..

this is the code for sending data to GS

```
API service using WiFi Client through PushingBox then relayed to Google @ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PuLae58fKfvN_ZnHHgYrBwy52JpvlNAgfhfxFYPM/edit#gid=0
  if (client2.connect(WEBSITE, 80))
  {
    client2.print("GET /pushingbox?devid=" + devid
                  + "&humidityData=" + (String) fHum
                  + "&celData="      + (String) fTemp

                 );

    // HTTP 1.1 provides a persistent connection, allowing batched requests
    // or pipelined to an output buffer
    client2.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client2.print("Host: ");
    client2.println(WEBSITE);
    client2.println("User-Agent: MKR1000/1.0");
    client2.println();
    Serial.println("\nData Sent");
  }

  connect(); // this is to reconnect to MQTT client after it auto disconnects aftr each send.
}
```

unless there is a known issue between the two I am not sure what can be done, it must be something to do with the above code clashing with MQTT client??

When I comment it out there are no issues.

any thoughts.

Thank-you.

incase the issue is in this section.

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include <MQTT.h>
#include <DHT.h>;
#include <DHT_U.h>

//////////Constants\\\\\\\

#define DHTPIN 6     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino

///////Variables\\\\\\\\

int chk;
float hum;  //Stores humidity value
float temp; //Stores temperature value
bool SheetBegin = false;

String Temp_str;
String Hum_str;
String Payload;

char Atemp[50];
char AHum[50];

float fTemp;
float fHum;

unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

int  fehrData = 0;
int  hicData = 0;
int hifData = 0;


const char ssid[] = "*";
const char pass[] = "*";

const char WEBSITE[] = "api.pushingbox.com"; //pushingbox API server
const String devid = "v7E593DA053CAC70"; //device ID on Pushingbox for our Scenario


WiFiClient client2;
MQTTClient client;





void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  client.begin("broker.shiftr.io", client2);
  client.onMessageAdvanced(messageReceived);
  dht.begin();


  connect();
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();

  if (!client.connected()) {
    connect();
  }
  ReadSensortoclient1();

  if (SheetBegin) {
    Serial.println("printing to sheets");
    //SendToSheets();
  }


}

void ReadSensortoclient1() {
  //Read data and store it to variables hum and temp
  fHum = dht.readHumidity();
  fTemp = dht.readTemperature();
  //Print temp and humidity values to serial monitor
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(fHum);
  Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
  Serial.print(fTemp);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");
  delay(2000); //Delay 2 sec.

  Temp_str = String(fTemp); //converting ftemp (the float variable above) to a string
  Temp_str.toCharArray(Atemp, Temp_str.length() + 1); //packaging up the data to publish to mqtt whoa...

  Hum_str = String(fHum); //converting Humidity (the float variable above) to a string
  Hum_str.toCharArray(AHum, Hum_str.length() + 1); //packaging up the data to publish to mqtt whoa...


  // publish a message roughly 2 second.
  if (millis() - lastMillis > 2000) {
    lastMillis = millis();
    client.publish("TempTopic", Atemp);
    client.publish("HumidityTopic", AHum);

  }
}



void SendToSheets() {
  //API service using WiFi Client through PushingBox then relayed to Google @ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PuLae58fZ0KfvN_ZnHHgYrBwy52JpvlNAgfhfxFYPM/edit#gid=0
  if (client2.connect(WEBSITE, 80))
  {
    client2.print("GET /pushingbox?devid=" + devid
                  + "&humidityData=" + (String) fHum
                  + "&celData="      + (String) fTemp

                 );

    // HTTP 1.1 provides a persistent connection, allowing batched requests
    // or pipelined to an output buffer
    client2.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client2.print("Host: ");
    client2.println(WEBSITE);
    client2.println("User-Agent: MKR1000/1.0");
    client2.println();
    Serial.println("\nData Sent");
  }

  connect();
}

void connect() {
  Serial.print("checking wifi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("\nconnecting...");
  while (!client.connect("Sender", "6ddf11", "027c44da6fa7006")) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nconnected to sender!");
  client.subscribe("SheetTopic");


}
void messageReceived(MQTTClient * client, char topic[], char payload[], int payload_length) {

  if (strcmp(payload, "Start") == 0) {
    SheetBegin = true;
    Serial.println(SheetBegin);
  }

  else if (strcmp(payload, "End") == 0) {
    SheetBegin = false;
    Serial.println(SheetBegin);
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is in the code you didn't post

Comment: Hi, I have added te entirety for clarity.

Comment: I would add `client2.stop();` (after reading the response)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response! However, in this case, it did not help the situation :(